# Solution for filter() not working within a For Loop?

Tags: r, loops, filter

I'm trying to fit a von Bertalanffy growth function (VGBF) in r to my data grouped by a serial number.
This is a snippet of my data:

```
Serial_No<- c(315,315,315,315,315,315,315,316,316,316,316,317,317,317,317,317,317,317,317,317,318,318,318,318,319,319,319,319)

Year<-c(1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945)

tl<-c(19,33,46,55,63,66,70,22,39,55,65,20,40,51,56,60,62,63,64,65,26,43,54,60,28,43,53,61)

age<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4))

df<-data.frame(Serial_No, Year, tl, age)
```

I've been following this example: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/01/von-bertalanffy-growth-plots-ii/
and have changed my code to as follows:

```
vb <- vbFuns()
predict2 <- function(x) predict(x,data.frame(age=ages))

agesum <- group_by(df,Serial_No) %>%
summarize(minage=min(age),maxage=max(age))

Serial_Nos <- unique(df$Serial_No)
nSerial_Nos <- length(Serial_Nos)

cfs <- cis <- preds1 <- preds2 <- NULL

for (i in 1:nSerial_Nos) {
 cat(Serial_Nos[i],"Loop\n")
 tmp1 <- filter(df,Serial_No==Serial_Nos[i])
 sv1 <- vbStarts(tl~age,data=tmp1)
 fit1 <- nls(tl~vb(age,Linf,K,t0),data=tmp1,start=sv1)
 cfs <- rbind(cfs,coef(fit1))
 boot1 <- Boot(fit1)
 tmp2 <-  confint(boot1)
 cis <- rbind(cis,c(tmp2["Linf",],tmp2["K",],tmp2["t0",]))
 ages <- seq(-1,16,0.2)
 boot2 <- Boot(fit1,f=predict2)
 tmp2 <- data.frame(Serial_No=Serial_Nos[i],age=ages,
                 predict(fit1,data.frame(age=ages)),
                 confint(boot2))
 preds1 <- rbind(preds1,tmp2)
 tmp2 <- filter(tmp2,age>=agesum$minage[i],age<=agesum$maxage[i])
 preds2 <- rbind(preds2,tmp2)
}
```

The code runs, but the results from the VBGF returned are the same for every serial no, which can't be the case. I think it's the filter function not working in the above code.

I've searched for solutions but can't get it to work.

If anyone can please help, or knows of a solution i'd really appreciate it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Which package? There seems to be one that is not `base R`

Comment: Should probably be `cat(Year[i],"Loop\n")` instead of `cat(years[i],"Loop\n")`, right? The missing packages, it seems are `FSA` and `car`, right?

Comment: Sorry, the packages are : library(FSAdata) 
library(FSA)    
library(car)     
library(dplyr)   
library(ggplot2)

Comment: Thank you, i'll try that (Have just edited the code above as years should have been changed to my data Serial_Nos)

Comment: Sorry, the code (after loading all the required packages) produces an error: `Error in out[[j]][[typelab]] : subscript out of bounds` and many warnings

Comment: Thanks for your comments, after running the code, tmp 1 only ever returns the data for 1 serial no, so i think this is where the error comes from?  I don't think the filter function is working. Can you shed any light on this? many thanks

Comment: You may consider package **growthrates** for fitting a series of "von Bert" functions.

Comment: I don't think that the main problem lies in the `filter` function, so  it may be wise to change the title of the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Model fit with package **growthrates**

The following post describes an alternative approach without for-loop and `filter`. Similar loop-free solutions can be implemented using the common `nls` function and `lapply` in "base" **R** or `group_by` in "tidyverse".

### Model definition

The **growthrates** package does not contain a von Bertalanffy function, so it has to be provided as user supplied model, as described in the [package vignette](https://tpetzoldt.github.io/growthrates/doc/User_models.html). Here I borrowed the function from package **FSA** and adapted it accordingly:

```r
library("growthrates")

grow_von_bert <- function(time, parms) {
  with(as.list(parms), {
    y <- Linf * (1 - exp(-K * (time - t0)))
    as.matrix(data.frame(time = time, y = y))
  })
}
```

### Test of the model with a single example

```r
p <- c(t0=5, Linf=10, K=.1)
time <- seq(5, 100)
plot(grow_von_bert(time, p), type="l")
```

### Fit of a single data example

It is always a good idea to fit one or more single examples first, before doing this for all.

```r
df1 <- subset(df, Serial_No == 315)
fit1 <- fit_growthmodel(df1$age, df1$tl,
                        FUN = grow_von_bert,  p=c(t0=0, Linf=70, K=0.1))
summary(fit1)
```

### Fit of all data sets

This can be done in a loop or with appropriate `tidyverse` functions, whipe package **growthrates** has such a function already built in, so all models can be fitted with a single function call. It is of course necessary to specify good start parameters, either the same for all curves or individual parameter sets, depending on the quality of the data. Here is the complete code including the data of the OP:

```r
library("growthrates")

df <- data.frame(
  Serial_No = factor(c(315,315,315,315,315,315,315,316,316,316,316,317,317,317,317,
                       317,317,317,317,317,318,318,318,318,319,319,319,319)),
  year = c(1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,
          1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945,1945),
  tl = c(19,33,46,55,63,66,70,22,39,55,65,20,40,51,56,60,62,63,64,65,26,43,54,60,28,
         43,53,61),
  age = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4)
)

grow_von_bert <- function(time, parms) {
  with(as.list(parms), {
    y <- Linf * (1 - exp(-K * (time - t0)))
    as.matrix(data.frame(time = time, y = y))
  })
}


fit <- all_growthmodels(tl ~ age | Serial_No, 
                        data=df, 
                        FUN = grow_von_bert,
                        p=c(t0=0, Linf=70, K=0.1))

results(fit)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
plot(fit, las=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comments, I wasn't aware of the growthrates package. For some reason though it's taking a very long time to run?? nearly 40 minutes already and this is just for the subset of my data, have a file with 6000+ serial numbers to run next.

Comment: Nonlinear optimization takes time and 6000+ nonlinear fits is a considerable number. You can speed up by specifying good start parameters or by changing the optimization algorithm. Nonlinear optimization can be an art and it can also be that another package is faster. **growthrates** builds up on **FME** that itself imports different other optimizer packages. My main message was, that an **improved structure** can help to avoid errors. There are of course many other ways, see https://CRAN.R-project.org/view=Optimization

Comment: Of course, thank you for your help